# Why epoll_wait() doesn't react on dup2(writable_fd, non_writable_fd)?

Tags: linux, epoll, dup2

Let's imagine I added non writable fd to epoll watcher to wait when it will become writable.

```
epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, non_writable_fd, {EPOLLOUT})
```

`non_writable_fd` still non writable and `epoll_wait` will return 0 ready fds

Then I'll make this

```
dup2(writable_fd, non_writable_fd)
```

Where `writable_fd` is a file descriptor which is writable. Now I am expecting that `epoll_wait` will return 1 fd immediately. But unfortunetly it still timeouts with 0 fd returned.

Why this technique doesn't work with `epoll` when it works with `select` and `poll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `epoll` cares about "*open file descriptions*", not about file descriptors. The answer is hidden in a few layers of man pages. First, `epoll_wait`:

> Will closing a file descriptor cause it to be **removed from all epoll
>   sets automatically**?
>
> **Yes**, but be aware of the following point.  A file
>   descriptor is a reference to an open file description (see
>   open(2))[...]

Back to your `dup2` call:

```
dup2(writable_fd, non_writable_fd)
```

`dup2` call atomically first closes `non_writable_fd` and then makes it point to the same file description as `writable_fd`. Consider 2 cases:

1. You didn't do anything special so your `dup2` ends up closing the open file description associated with `non_writable_fd`. In this case `epoll` simply removes it from the set and that's that
2. You had beforehand `dup`'d `non_writable_fd` into something else. In this case `dup2` simply severs the association between `non_writable_fd` and its OFD, which lives on, watched by `epoll`

In both situations your `dup` call doesn't achieve what you want: you need to explicitly call `epoll_ctl` again.

Comment: Right! But I think that they are called _open file descriptions_ or OFD for short. You missed the _open_ piece.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks! Feel free to edit (or I can, in a few minutes).